# Receiving a PDF document via HTTP

Tags: node.js, http, .net-core, httpclient

I have a web-api that parses HTML and converts it to PDF:

```js
  /**
     * converts html to pdf
     * @param request
     * @param response
     */
    public fromHtml(request: Request, response: Response) {
        let body = request.body;
        if(!body){
            throw new ValidationError("No html");
        }
        // package: pdf-html
        pdf.create(request.body).toStream((err, stream) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new ValidationError(err.message);
            } else {
                response.set('Content-type', Types.PDF);
                // stream = ReadStream
                stream.pipe(response)
            }
        });
    }
```

Now I try to get that data as byte[] within my project-service (`.net core`):

```cs
public async byte[] HtmlToPdf(string html)
{
    StringContent content = new StringContent(html, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/api/pdf/from-html", content);
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    byte[] pdf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
    return pdf;
}
```

But receiving the data, the response-body (responseString) is cut and thus the pdf-file broken.
Now I'm not sure where the failure is.

Is the failure on document-service or project side?
Do I send the data from document-service wrong?

What is the best way of handling files like PDF, Imgs etc. via http? Is it better to endode the files as Base64?

Comment: Try using `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` instead of `ReadAsStringAsync` and the encoding stuff.

Comment: oh yes. So easy. Reading the data directly as byte[] and write it to file everything works. Great. Many thanks. bizarrely ,parsing the byte[] to a string the string is cut again.